# If all elements of a sequence $x_n$ are in a set $M$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$ is in $M$ as well? Why?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm wondering if this is true, for example if $M:=[1,3)$ then $\sup(M)=3$ but 3 is not in $M$.

Comment: You should wonder why you found a counter-example and are still wondering if it is true or not. Logically speaking, if you are wondering if a statement is true and you found a counter-example, then it is not true as a general statement. (It might be true if you add some *conditions* though! See the answer below.)

Comment: As you demonstrated, the result is not true in general. For example $x_n=3-1/n$ is in $M$ for all $M$ but does not converge to an element in $M$. In a metric space, a set is called closed when all limits of sequences inside the set are contained in it.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I asking because I found this statement in a book

Comment: Given the fact that "every irrational number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers," note that this would imply every single real number is rational.

Comment: Which book? Please be specific. The mistake is so massive that, untill proven otherwise, my bet would be on a faulty *reading* rather than on a faulty text (but hey, this universe is full of mysteries...).

Answer (score 5):

This is not true in general, but will hold if $M$ is a closed set.

For a counterexample, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ is included in $M=(0,\infty)$, yet the limit is $0\notin M$.

Comment: (Regarding the first point, I suppose there may be topological subtleties according to whether we are in a [first-countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set#Properties_of_closed_sets) or not, but for all purposes I would say the above statement is sufficient ("everything I care about is a first-countable space"), and I do not know enough about these subtleties to cover them.)

Comment: Doesn't M need to be complete instead of closed?

Comment: Err. No? A complete space has to do with Cauchy sequences (in a complete space, every Cauchy sequence is convergent in the space), not per se with the limit points belonging to the set.

Comment: If a sequence converges then its also Cauchy right?

Comment: Yes. But completeness is not necessary.. closed is sufficient. What you want to use is that if a convergent sequence is in a complete space, then it is Cauchy because convergent, therefore convergent (!) in the space. But it suffices for the space to be closed (whether it be metric, complete or not, modulo the topological subtlety above): any convergent sequence in the closed set will have its limit belonging to the closed set.

Comment: Take $M = (0, \infty)$ as the space. M is closed in itself yet the sequence you defined does not converge in M and thus the limit is not in M. Isn't this why you need completness? (M isn't complete)

Comment: $M$ is not closed *in $\mathbb{R}$*, i.e. the topological space in question. Note that the OP's question presupposes the sequence converges. So I am considering the question wrt a topological space where the sequence has a limit -- the one where the sequence converges.

Comment: More specifically, if you really want the fine print you have to specify the space you are working on. The OP's question is basically *"if a sequence converges in some space $X$ to a limit $\ell\in X$, with all elements of the sequence belonging to some subset $M\subseteq X$, can we conclude that $\ell\in M$?"*

Comment: Alright, then I agree that closed is sufficient.